# Combination of flavors

Tags: combinatorics

We want to make ice cream cones using some choices from 4 flavors, but with the following rules:
None of the 4 can be used in all 3 cones and, for any 2 cones, there is at least 1 flavor at both of them but not at the 3rd one. In how many ways can we make these 3 cones while satisfying the constraints?

Each cone can have from 0 up to 4 flavors but using the constraints, we deduce that we can only have 2 or 3 in each of them.
More specifically, we can't have 3 flavors at all 3 cones, we can only have 3+3+2 or 3+2+2 or 2+2+2 - right?
I have counted 6+24+4 ways in total, so 34 and this number x 6 for the rotation of the 3 cones (assuming they are distinct). Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is entirely right, but I believe you've miscounted the ways of having 3+2+2 flavours.

Since each pair of cones must share one flavour that the third doesn't have, and there are ways of choosing a pair of cones, three of your flavours must be assigned in this way - e.g. flavour $A$ to cones $1$ and $2$, $B$ to cones $1$ and $3$, and $C$ to cones $2$ and $3$ - leaving one flavour, $D$.

As you rightly note, this leftover flavour can then either be placed on no cones, 1 cone, or 2 cones, but not all 3.

- If we have 2+2+2, one flavour is left out, and permuting the other three is the same as permuting cones. There are thus $4!/3! = 4$ ways to assign flavours.
- If we have 3+2+2, e.g. $ABD$, $AC$, and $BC$, then one flavour only appears once, and on the 3-scoop cone ($D$) and one flavour is not on that cone ($C$). Swapping the other two flavours ($A$ and $B$) is the same as swapping the 2-scoop cones, so $A$ and $B$ are indistinguishable. So there are $4!/2! = 12$ ways of doing this. **This is where we differ**.
- If we have 3+3+2, e.g. $AB$, $ACD$, and $BCD$, then swapping $A$ and $B$ is equivalent to swapping the latter two cones, while $C$ and $D$ are clearly indistinguishable from each other. We have two pairs of indistinguishable flavours, so there are $4!/(2!*2!)=6$ ways of assigning flavours.

For each case we can then permute the cones, and there are as you say $6$ ways of doing this. I thus get a total of $(4+12+6)*6 = 22*6 = 132$.

Comment: Linell: Yes, I just noticed it is 4x3, not 4x3x2. We combine the 4th ingredient left out with the one that is not common between the first two (3,2). Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries, I had to double check to make sure I wasn't making a mistake somewhere. Combinatorics + me + Friday afternoons can be a dangerous mixture!